# Averge from values of a .txt file Python

Tags: python

This is what my `txt` file looks like:

```
Blancke Karen:16:15:17:15:18
Boddin Sophie:10:10:10:11:9
Bogaert Tim:12:12:13:13:11
Bossuyt Giovanni:14:20:19:19:17
Boucherie Bram:13:12:12:13:12
Brion Mathias:17:18:14:15:9
Brock Christophe:13:12:12:13:8
Brockhoven Karel:12:12:12:13:16
Bruggeman Koen:12:13:12:13:9
Brutyn Andy:3:6:3:6:7
Bulckaen Maarten:11:10:11:11:12
Buster Tim:14:18:17:15:10
Buyse Woudewin:18:15:19:15:20
Caes Roy:8:9:2:0:3
Caljon Thibald:10:10:10:11:12
```

How do I get the average of all the values by name?

I read already many topics about kind of the same question but I found none with a txt file like this one.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `"I read already many topics about kind of the same question but i found none with a txt file like this one"` this is a CSV file, but using `:` as a separator/delimiter instead of a comma so you can try to adapt a CSV solution that I'm sure you found. Otherwise ask a question about a specific problem you have

Comment: Have you opened the file, read a line and split it by `:`... Have you seen how to convert text to integers etc...? Which part do you need help with specifically?

Comment: Break your problem down into pieces. What you want to do is 1) read the file's content, 2) split the lines to get the names and according numbers, 3) convert the numbers from string to numeric (e.g. float) 4) calculate the averages for each name, 5) access the result somehow, e.g. print it to the console.

Comment: Tip: `df = pd.read_csv("mytxt.txt", delimiter=':', header=None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas` it's easy:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("mytxt.txt", delimiter=':', header=None)

# If you just want to see the results
df.mean(axis=1,numeric_only=True)

# Create a new column to store the results
df['average'] = df.mean(axis=1,numeric_only=True)

df.head(5)
                  0   1   2   3   4   5  average
0     Blancke Karen  16  15  17  15  18     16.2
1     Boddin Sophie  10  10  10  11   9     10.0
2       Bogaert Tim  12  12  13  13  11     12.2
3  Bossuyt Giovanni  14  20  19  19  17     17.8
4    Boucherie Bram  13  12  12  13  12     12.4
```

The txt used in this example: https://gofile.io/?c=I6rLX0

Answer (score 0):

> I read already many topics about kind of the same question but i found none with a txt file like this one.

Because it's two separate quests.

Read file and split values.

```py
with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    table = [line.rstrip().split(':') for line in f]
```

Now you have table like:

```py
table = [ ['Blancke Karen', '16', '15', '17', '15', '18'],
          ... ]
```

Change structure and convert numbers:

```py
data = {row[0]: list(map(int, row[1:])) for row in table}
```

And you have something like:

```py
data = { 'Blancke Karen': [16, 15, 17, 15, 18],
         ... }
```

And then use what you find to get average.